# Action Menu Item not showing up on the action menu when extending ActionBarActivity

Tags: android

I am trying to create a action menu item on an activity. I want to have a plus icon on the top right corner so that the user can click on it and add new things.

When I using the default extends ActionBarActivity, the menu item is automatically added to the overflow menu (the three dot symbol).  ![enter image description here][1]

When I changed it to extends Activity, it works as I wanted. the plus symbol appears on the top right corner. 
![enter image description here][2]
Is there a way to using ActionBarActivity and still get the result I want?

Thanks

Here is what's in the main.xml in the menu folder:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"
    android:title="Add"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

to

```
 app:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

Also i believe you have the name space defined for `app`.

Note: If there is not enough space to display item in actionbar it appears in the overflow menu.